# Powershell not handling string parameters properly

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a simple powershell script, and I don't understand its behavior. Here is the code.

```
Function print($first,$second){
Write-Host "$first"
}

$one="Dog"
$two="Cat"

print($one,$two)
```

And here is the output.

```
Dog Cat
```

I don't know why its printing both parameters instead of just the one that I asked for. I found a similar question posted that says the answer to the solution is to write

```
print $one $two
```

But I don't know why.
The other question is at [How do I pass multiple string parameters to a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732/powershell-how-do-i-pass-string-parameters-correctly)

Can anyone illuminate on this subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you have to call it as:

```
print $one $two
```

In Powershell, arguments to functions are delimited with space and not comma and are not enclosed in parentheses ( method arguments are, though)

The way you were calling, `print($one,$two)`, it is like calling print with one argument which is an array - `($one,$two)`. So when you `write-host $first`, you are echoing the array and hence you see them both.